# How to solve Laravel Excel sheets issue?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-excel

**Where can I find this `onlySheets` Method ?**

I wanna import data from Excel file that contains sheet called "Clients".

I've created a `ClientsImport.php` file :

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;

class ClientsImport implements WithMultipleSheets
{
    // MULTIPLE SHEETS
    public function sheets(): array
    {
        return [
            'clients' => new ClientsSheetImport(),
        ];
    }
    // END MULTIPLE SHEETS
}
```

and Then created `ClientSheetImport.php` file to get rows and validate data from given Excel file :

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;
// use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMappedCells;
use App\Client;

class ClientsSheetImport implements ToModel, WithValidation, WithMappedCells
{
  /**
   * @param array $row
   *
   * @return Client|null
   */
  public function model(array $row)
  {
      return new Client([
          'nrc_entrp' => $row['nrc_entrp'],
          'raisoci' => $row['raisoci'],

      ]);
  }

  public function rules(): array {
      return [
        'nrc_entrp'=> 'required|unique:clients|max:20',
        'raisoci'=> 'required|unique:clients|max:100',
      ];
  }
  public function mapping(): array
  {
      return [
        'nrc_entrp' => 'B1',
        'raisoci' => 'B2',
        
      ];
  } // mapping

}
```

and in `ImportClientController.php` I wanna import one Sheet from Excel file ("Clients" sheet") with this Given Code :

```
  $import_client = new ClientsImport();
  $import_client->onlySheets('clients');
  Excel::import($import_client, $file_url);
```

But I got this error :

```
Call to undefined method App\Imports\ClientsImport::onlySheets()
```

Where can I find this `onlySheets` Method ?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/search?q=%22function+onlySheets%22

Comment: Thank You for ur help

Answer (score 1):

I do this and it works.
Adding this:

```
class UserImport implement ...{
use WithConditionalSheets;
 public function conditionalSheets(): array
    {
        return [
            'Sheet1' => new ReadImport(),
        ];
    }
...
}
```